# how to debug gwt app server side code?

Tags: gwt, maven, jetty

i have a maven gwt application with maven-jetty plugin, i tried to to debug the code with 'mvn jetty:run-war' and 'mvn gwt:debug', it start the application in gwt dev mode so i can debug the client side code but not the server side, how can i debug both the client side and server side code? i tried 'mvnDebug jetty:run-exploded', it said:

```
Preparing to Execute Maven in Debug Mode
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

then i brought up a browser point it to localhost:8000, nothing loaded and in the terminal it spitted out the message:

```
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >GET / HTTP/1.1< - excepted >JDWP-Handshake<
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >GET / HTTP/1.1< - excepted >JDWP-Handshake<
Debugger failed to attach: timeout during handshake
```

i have no clue what it mean? anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 8000 in the case you listed is the port that your *remote debugger* will connect to your remote instance, it is not for you to view the application. The GUI itself is most likely available over 8080 or 8888, but that depends on the config in Jetty or if you're running in Hosted Mode.

You need to connect a remote debugger to Jetty, like Eclipse or NetBeans whatever your IDE is.

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging+Jetty+with+Eclipse
http://www.vijaykiran.com/2009/05/12/debugging-maven-jetty-web-application-in-netbeans/

Using Hosted Mode might be helpful as well:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_hosted_mode_instead_of_GWT's

More Advanced:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: inally got it work, basic just  run 'mvnDebug jetty:run-war -P\!build-rpm'(i use mac, rpm wont' work on mac), then in eclipse configure
a remote debugger to port 8000 for server side; in another terminal run 'mvn -P\!build-rpm gwt:debug', go back to
eclipse configure another remote debugger to port 8021 for client side, then finally in bring up browser point to the
index page, it hit the side code right away. because of our pom configure, the gwt development mode don't start any server(jetty or tomcat), we have to start the jetty specifically.

Answer (score 1):

From your IDE you have to create remote debugging after launching debug from maven. In Eclipse you can do this by going to the `Debug Configuration` and create new `Remote Java Application` configuration. Then just refresh the page of your app in browser and start debugging.

If you use some other IDE, you have to find out how to use remote debugging for it by yourself. It is pretty much the same everywhere.